# Every monad is an applicative functor — generalizing to other categories

Tags: haskell, categories, functor, applicative, category-theory

I can readily enough define general `Functor` and `Monad` classes in Haskell:

```
class (Category s, Category t) => Functor s t f where
    map :: s a b -> t (f a) (f b)

class Functor s s m => Monad s m where
    pure :: s a (m a)
    join :: s (m (m a)) (m a)
    join = bind id
    bind :: s a (m b) -> s (m a) (m b)
    bind f = join . map f
```

I'm reading [this post](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/06/applicative-functors/) which explains an applicative functor is a lax (closed or monoidal) functor. It does so in terms of a (exponential or monoidal) bifunctor. I know in the Haskell category, every `Monad` is `Applicative`; how can we generalize? How should we choose the (exponential or monoidal) functor in terms of which to define `Applicative`? What confuses me is our `Monad` class seems to have no notion whatsoever of the (closed or monoidal) structure.

Edit: A commenter says it is not generally possible, so now part of my question is where it is possible.

Comment: I seem to recall that this is *not* generally true, and relies on the extra (closed, etc.) structure of Hask.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Constrained.html#t:Monoidal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What confuses me is our Monad class seems to have no notion whatsoever of the (closed or monoidal) structure.

If I understood your question correctly, that would be provided via the tensorial strength of the monad. The `Monad` class doesn't have it because it is intrinsic to the **Hask** category. More concretely, it is assumed to be:

```
t :: Monad m => (a, m b) -> m (a,b)
t (x, my) = my >>= \y -> return (x,y)
```

Comment: So in general, `Applicative` is **not** a superclass of `Monad`? Rather they are both superclasses of (say) `StrongMonad`? (And i guess `Applicative` can't even be defined unless the category is monoidal?)

Comment: That is my understanding. In particular `(<*>) = ap` and in a general setting `ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b` requires tensorial strength (more obvious if we uncurry it).

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, all the monoidal stuff involved in the methods of a monoidal functor happens on the target category. It can be formalised thus<sup>†</sup>:

```
class (Category s, Category t) => Functor s t f where
  map :: s a b -> t (f a) (f b)

class Functor s t f => Monoidal s t f where
  pureUnit :: t () (f ())
  fzip :: t (f a,f b) (f (a,b))
```

`s`-morphisms only come in if you consider the laws of a monoidal functor, which roughly say that the monoidal structure of `s` should be mapped into this monoidal structure of `t` by the functor.

Perhaps more insightful is to factor an `fmap` into the class methods, so it's clear what the “func-”-part of the functor does:

```
class Functor s t f => Monoidal s t f where
  ...
  puref :: s () y -> t () (f y)
  puref f = map f . pureUnit
  fzipWith :: s (a,b) c -> t (f a,f b) (f c)
  fzipWith f = map f . fzip
```

From `Monoidal`, we can get back our good old **Hask**-`Applicative` thus:

```
pure :: Monoidal (->) (->) f => a -> f a
pure a = puref (const a) ()

(<*>) :: Monoidal (->) (->) f => f (a->b) -> f a -> f b
fs <*> xs = fzipWith (uncurry ($)) (fs, xs)
```

or

```
liftA2 :: Monoidal (->) (->) f => (a->b->c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f xs ys = fzipWith (uncurry f) (xs,ys)
```

Perhaps more interesting in this context is the other direction, because that shows us up the connection to monads in the generalised case:

```
instance Applicative f => Monoidal (->) (->) f where
  pureUnit = pure
  fzip = \(xs,ys) -> liftA2 (,) xs ys
       = \(xs,ys) -> join $ map (\x -> map (x,) ys) xs
```

That lambdas and tuple sections aren't available in a general category, however they can be [translated to cartesian closed categories](http://conal.net/blog/posts/overloading-lambda).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I'm using `(,)` as the product in both monoidal categories, with identity element `()`. More generally you might write `data I_s` and `data I_t` and `type family (⊗) x y` and `type family (∙) x y` for the products and their respective identity elements.</sub>

Comment: You may well be right, maybe I'm missing something. Looking at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) of monoidal functor though, the natural transformation Φ: FA ⊗ FB -> F(A⊗B), in the case of an endofunctor, seems to be just the monad's strength no?  not as I wrote it but it's pretty straightforward to derive a strength `t': TA ⊗ TB -> T (A⊗B)` from `t: A ⊗ TB -> T (A⊗B)`. Is it something else I'm missing here?

Comment: I think it begs the question, to use `(,)` as the product.

Comment: @MFarkas-Dyck not sure. You definitely _need_ some CCC helpers to connect the monoidal-functor and monad classes, and in any CCC the product will essentially behave as a tuple (even if you don't use Haskell tuples). But, if I'm wrong I'd be excited to see a counterexample.